# Hover over image in group, effect remaining images within group?

Tags: css, hover, grayscale

Through CSS only, I was hoping you guys can help me achieve the following behavior:
There are there three groups (div class); `.green`, `.red`, and `.blue`. within a group are images that are set as `filter: grayscale(100%);`. Upon hover state, the image restores it's color (`filter: grayscale(0%);`).

So here's the part I'm trying to figure out: If an image is on a hoverstate, how can I make it effect the remaining images within it's group?

I've put together a [jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/kenhimself/gu6m1hae/).

Comment: means you want to do something like this https://jsfiddle.net/gu6m1hae/5/ ?

Comment: if I understood, you want `grayscale`-effect for all images in this group when hover one element of this group?

Comment: Yes! Thank you @Vitorinofernandes

Answer (score 2):

- I have changed `:hover` state to parent

demo - https://jsfiddle.net/gu6m1hae/5/

```
.green:hover img,
.red:hover img,
.blue:hover img {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
  filter: grayscale(0%);
  filter: gray;
}`
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<div class="green">
  <img src="http://i67.tinypic.com/2433fok.jpg"/>
  <img src="http://i67.tinypic.com/2433fok.jpg"/>
  <img src="http://i67.tinypic.com/2433fok.jpg"/>
</div>

<div class="red">
  <img src="http://i65.tinypic.com/fy1ieq.jpg"/>
  <img src="http://i65.tinypic.com/fy1ieq.jpg"/>
  <img src="http://i65.tinypic.com/fy1ieq.jpg"/>
  <img src="http://i65.tinypic.com/fy1ieq.jpg"/>
  <img src="http://i65.tinypic.com/fy1ieq.jpg"/>
  <img src="http://i65.tinypic.com/fy1ieq.jpg"/>
</div>

<div class="blue">
  <img src="http://i65.tinypic.com/sz7mnp.jpg"/>
  <img src="http://i65.tinypic.com/sz7mnp.jpg"/>
  <img src="http://i65.tinypic.com/sz7mnp.jpg"/>
  <img src="http://i65.tinypic.com/sz7mnp.jpg"/>
  <img src="http://i65.tinypic.com/sz7mnp.jpg"/>
  <img src="http://i65.tinypic.com/sz7mnp.jpg"/>
  <img src="http://i65.tinypic.com/sz7mnp.jpg"/>
</div>

img {  
  position:relative; 
  display:block; 
  float:left; 
  width:auto; 
  height:200px; 
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); 
  -moz-filter: grayscale(100%); 
  filter: grayscale(100%); 
  filter: gray;
}

div:hover img {  
 -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%); 
 filter: grayscale(0%); 
 filter: gray;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Igor_Ivancha/gu6m1hae/6/)